# function using initial state object instead of using the updated state react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, object

this is my first question, so basically i've a notification object and I've attached a firebase onValue listners which fires the handleNotification function everytime a new value is being added, problem is that the handleNotification fn is not using the updated notification state

```
const [notification, setNotification] = useState({
  id: '',
  total: '',
  lastTotal: '',
  count: '',
});
 
const handleNotification = (channelId, snap, notification) => {
    console.log('notification before -------', notification);
  if (notification.id === '') {
    let obj = {
      id: channelId,
      total: snap.size,
      lastKnownTotal: snap.size,
      count: 0,
    };
    setNotification({ ...obj });
      return console.log('notification after -------', notification);
  }
  
  // the above if statement runs even when notification.id is already populated, the below code should run instead of that
  
  let obj2 = {
    ...notification,
  };
  if (snap.size - obj2.total > 0) {
    setNotification((prev) => ({ ...prev, count: snap.size - obj2.total }));
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onValue(
    ref(db, 'messages' + '/' + channel.id),
    (snap) => {
      if (channel) {
        handleNotification(channel.id, snap, notification);
      } else {
        console.log('////');
      } 
    }
  );
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

State updates happens in async way, thats why you are still seeing the old state. You can put the console.log outside the function, that will output the updated state.

```
const handleNotification = (channelId, snap, notification) => {
  console.log('notification before -------', notification);
  if (notification.id === '') {
    let obj = {
      id: channelId,
      total: snap.size,
      lastKnownTotal: snap.size,
      count: 0,
    };
    setNotification({ ...obj });
    return;
  }
  
  // the above if statement runs even when notification.id is already populated, the below code should run instead of that
  
  let obj2 = {
    ...notification,
  };
  if (snap.size - obj2.total > 0) {
    setNotification((prev) => ({ ...prev, count: snap.size - obj2.total }));
  }
};
console.log('notification after -------', notification);
```